# .png file has only one channel read by python while 4 RGBA channels by C?

Tags: c, png

I used python to read a `.png` image and the array is shaped `2048 x 2048`, with one channel per pixel.

```
import numpy as np
img = np.array(imread('test.png'))
height, width = img.shape # 2048 x 2048
```

However, it seems that every pixel in `.png` files should have 4 channels(i.e R,G,B,A).

Now I have to switch from `python` to `C`.

I'm confused how should I read the image. The question is, the image I want to read is a **2-color-image**, which means I don't need to care about the RGBA values.

So why the python code gives that result? And how can I handle `.png` file under this circumstance?

P.S: I use [PNG.h](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) to read `.png` file in `C`.

Comment: It gives that result because the library was made that way. If it's a two-color image that's reasonable. And there certainly are ways to make it RGBA. But it you don't care about that then what is the actual problem here?

Comment: I'm confused because I thought there may be some parameters in the file header that shows the file has 4 channels or only one channel. So I'm not sure the values read by my C code is of 4 channels or 1.  I wonder how can I know about how to extract these values.